# WKWebView button Icon is available or not using javascript

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, wkwebview

In below code, I used to get icon class Name ('user-Edit').

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('user-Edit')") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Result: \(result)")
}
```

But result is nil. I get to know button is available in webView or not?

did anyone worked on it?

Comment: have you got the error?

Comment: No error @AndreyChernukha

Comment: Is button enclosed in <div>, just search for elementByID or name if not in Div

Comment: <span data-v-0221e2w12 title="This user is locked." class="nav-link-item user-Edit”>
</span>
@nkp

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodeList, not an element!

You need to acess the element you are looking for inside that list in the following way:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('user-Edit')[0].innerHTML") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Result: \(result)")
}
```